# Elasticsearch result

Tags: elasticsearch

I am writing queries in the Elasticsearch for my app.I need it to search within several indices and aggregate the result(For example, shows 3 items of each indices)like below.
I tested nested, aggregation, joining queries but it is not the answer.I need the result to be returned as below

```
{
    index1: [
        {item1},
        {item2},
    ],
    index2: [
        {item3},
        {item4},
        {item5},
    ]
}
```

Does anybody know what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do multi-index search and the use aggregation and sorting on based on **_index** metadata.
Your query should look like this:

```
GET index_1,index_2/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "_index": ["index_1", "index_2"] 
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "indices": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_index", 
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_index": { 
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "script_fields": {
    "index_name": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "doc['_index']" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For more information you can check ES official documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index-field.html).

Comment: Thank you Kaveh,the problem is that I need to use Fuzzy queries and the _index metadata  does not support regexp and fuzzy queries. Do you have any other suggestion?